# Как из экшена передать значение переменной в другой экшн? Smarty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty, tpl

Сайт реализован на `Smarty`.
Возникло желание добавить поиск на сайте.
Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу понять как передать из `searchproductAction`, то что она возвращает, сам он работает верно, но как использовать его значение не пойму.
`SearchController.php`:

```
function indexAction($smarty){
    $rsCategories = getAllMainCatsWithChildren();
    $text = isset($text) ? $text : null;

    $smarty->assign('text', $text);
    $smarty->assign('pageTitle', 'Поиск');
    $smarty->assign('rsCategories',$rsCategories);

    loadTemplate($smarty, 'header');
    loadTemplate($smarty, 'search');
    loadTemplate($smarty, 'footer');
}

function searchproductAction(){
    $search_box = $_POST['search_box'];
    $search_box = trim($search_box);
    $search_box = mysql_real_escape_string($search_box);
    $search_box = htmlspecialchars($search_box);

    if (empty($search_box)) {
        $resData['success'] = 0;
        $resData['message'] = 'Вы ничего не ввели в окно поиска';
        echo json_encode($resData);
        return;
    }

    if (strlen($search_box) < 3) {
        $resData['success'] = 0;
        $resData['message'] = 'Слишком короткий поисковый запрос';
    }
    else if (strlen($search_box) > 128) {
        $resData['success'] = 0;
        $resData['message'] = 'Слишком длинный поисковый запрос';
    }
    else {
        $text = 0;
        $res = searchTextProduct($search_box);

        if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
            $search_text = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
            $resData['success'] = 1;
            $resData['message'] = "По запросу $search_box найдено совпадений: $num";
            do {
                // Делаем запрос, получающий ссылки на продукты
                $res1=getLinkSearchProduct($search_text);
                if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                    $product = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1);
                }
                $text = $text . '<p><a href="/product/'.$product['id'].'/">'.$product['name'].'</a></p>';
            }
            while ($search_text = mysql_fetch_assoc($res));

            return $text;
        }
        else {
            $resData['success'] = 0;
            $resData['message'] = 'По вашему запросу ничего не найдено';
        }
    }
}
```

Форма поиска:

```
<form method="post" action="/search/">
    <input type="text" name="search_box" id="search_box" class='search_box' placeholder="Что искать?" />
    <input type="submit" value="Поиск" class="search_button" onclick="searchProduct();"/><br />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function searchProduct() {
    var search_box = $('#search_box').val();
    var postData = {search_box:search_box};

    $.ajax({    
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        url: "/search/searchproduct/",
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data['success']) {
                alert(data['message']);
                document.location = '/search/';
            }
            else {
                alert(data['message']);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

search.tpl:

```
<div class="text-info">
    {if isset($text)}
      По вашему искомому слову найдено:
      <br>
    {$text}
    {/if}
</div>
```

Работать все должно следующим образом: пользователем вводит слово, получает алерт с количеством найденных товаров, с данным словом, после чего на файл оболочка(`search.tpl`), выводит ссылку(и) и название(я) на данный продукт(ы)

Comment: какое то фиаско. если вы используете смарти то на кой черт вы пишите  генерацию html непосредственно в пхп ? генерите шаблон в строку, записывайте вывод `$resdata['content']` и выводите его на станицу при получении ответа. без всяких там перенаправлений.

Comment: зачем вы вообще используете `mysql_affected_rows` да и само устаревшее 10 лет назад расширение `mysql`. зачем в шаблоне проверять `isset`. шаблоны сделаны чтобы упростить максимально верстку. не надо там такого писать.

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чем у меня ошибка буду пытаться исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробую с утра подытожить свой вчерашний комментарий. с помощью аякса вы вызываете метод `searchproductAction`. Не надо строить логику так, что один раз этот метод возвращает json, в следующий html и так далее. Пусть он всегда возвращает json.

Чутка упростим вызов:

```
function searchProduct() {       
    var data = { search_box: $('#search_box').val() };
    $.post("/search/searchproduct/", data, function(result){
         alert(result.message);
         if(result.success){
            $("#results").html(result.content);
         }
    });
}
```

Таким образом, в случае успеха мы ожидаем, что в поле `content` будет содержаться html-код списка результатов поиска. И перенаправления нам тут не нужны. Если использовать переходы на другую страницу, то запрос надо записывать в сессию на стороне сервера. И после перехода на нужный экшен, использовать это сохраненное значение. Так что вопрос в том,реально вам надо открыть другую страницу, или достаточно разместить результат на текущей.

сам метод поиска начните с заполнения ответа по умолчанию, а закончите его отправкой.

```
function searchproductAction(){
    $search_box = ....;
    $result = ['sucess' => 0, 'message' => "По вашему запросу ничего не найдено" ];
    .....
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

при обработке строки запроса будете менять только сообщение об ошибке.
Далее, переходят к формированию результатов заведите новый шаблон `search_results.tpl` вида

```
{foreach $products as $p}
    <p><a href="/product/{$product.id}">{$product.name}</a></p>
{/foreach}
```

установите результат в 1 и соответствующее сообщение, извлеките записи из бд, и передайте их в шаблон. Затем выполните шаблон и запишите результат его выполнения в массив результата

```
 $result['success'] = 1
 $result['message'] =  "....";
 .....
 $smarty->assign('products', $products);    
 $result['content'] = $smarty->fetch('search_results.tpl');
```